# Frontend load generator for http traffic with selenium in Kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, selenium-webdriver

I have a few microservices in my k8s cluster and would like to create a load generator for the frontend service. I would prefer to use python and selenium.
I can run the tasks with different webdriver locally on my desktop. But it fails when trying it in the kubernetes cluster.
It looks like the task is not being started. Here is the script snipped:

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, between
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import json
import time
import random

def generate_random_cc_number():
    return "".join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(16)])

class WebAppUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
        capabilities.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())

        # Enable logging for browser and performance
        capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"browser": "ALL", "performance": "ALL"}

        # Connect to the Selenium standalone server instead of using ChromeDriverManager
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities=capabilities)

    @task
    def website_interactions(self):
        url = "http://10.0.184.192:3000"

        self.driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(1)
        random_cc = [1234567890123456, 1231231231231231, 6582134902356478, 123456789]

        address = "123 xyz"
        address_text_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter your address']").send_keys(address)
        time.sleep(1)
```

here are the logs from the pod/container executing the script:

```
3:52:37.741 INFO [GridModel.setAvailability] - Switching Node b76c3817-9f16-49f0-b55b-49f300d4235b (uri: http://10.244.0.238:4444) from DOWN to UP
13:52:37.743 INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node b76c3817-9f16-49f0-b55b-49f300d4235b at http://10.244.0.238:4444. Health check every 120s
13:52:37.990 INFO [Standalone.execute] - Started Selenium Standalone 4.11.0 (revision 040bc5406b): http://10.244.0.238:4444
```